# why "NaN" to Animated toValue setting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, expo

There was a problem while developing the reactnative app.
In the Animated.timing function , when I directly enter a number in toValue it works fine, but when I enter a calculated variable it doesn't work. Do you know why?

```
    const loaderValue = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
    
    const load = (count)=>{
        const val = Math.round((count/total) *100)
        console.log('val',val); // any number 30, 40, 50 ... good work print a number value
        Animated.timing(loaderValue,{
            toValue: Number(val), // not work -> "NaN"
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver:false,
        }).start();
    }
    
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(loaderValue); // log -> "NaN"
        load(now) // enter a number value
    },[now])
```

I tried to change the calculated value to function parseInt(), but not work

Comment: So what is the value of "val" ? My guess is that it isn't as numeric as you think it is

Comment: Not sure if this is your problem -> `console.log(loaderValue);`  But `loaderValue` is scoped, and as such is not going to update unless `now` changes.

Comment: I am trying to make a progress bar.  This is a component source. "now"  is the props for this component.
"now" input a number and display the progress bar.
"total" is the denominator value and "now" is the numerator value.
It is returned as "NaN" in the percentage conversion part.